# How to update more tables using ajax post with dynamic accept friends buttons?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a PHP file to accepting friends request.

**PHP**

```
session_start();
include 'db.php';
error_reporting(0);
$username= $_SESSION['username'];
$i=1;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='$username' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade DESC";
$user_query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($user_query);
if($numrows < 1){
echo "<center><p style='padding-left:0px;'>no more friend requests!<p></center>";
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$user1 = $row["user1"];
$logged_user= $row["user2"];
$i++;
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" id="child" style="background-color: #c2c2c2;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:20px;padding-top: 0px;padding-right:0px;">
`<img src="user/<?php echo $user1; ?>`/profile_pictures/<?php echo $user1; ?>.jpg" width="25px" height="25px"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-left:0px; margin-left: -10px;">
    <b><?php echo $user1 ?></b><br />
    <div id="accept_div">
    <input id="rcv_user" type="hidden" name="rcv_user" value="<?php echo $logged_user; ?>"/> 
    <input id="snd_usr" type="hidden" name="snd_usr" value="<?php echo $user1; ?>"/> 
    <input id="response" type="hidden" name="response" value="accept"/> 
<span id="accepted" class="" style="display:none">Accepted</span>
<span id="or">or</span> <a id="ignore" href="#"><button class="btn-xs btn-danger">Ignore</button></a>
```

**Javascript / jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#submit').each(function() {
$(this).click(function() {
 var ths = $(this);
var I = ths.attr("id");
var rcv_user = $(ths).siblings("#rcv_user").val();
var snd_usr = $(ths).siblings("#snd_usr").val();
var response = $(ths).siblings("#response").val();
$.post("respond_friend.php", {rcv_user:rcv_user, snd_usr:snd_usr, response:response},
function(value){
$('#child').css('background-color', 'white');
$("#submit").hide();
$("#ignore").hide();
$("#or").hide();
$("#accepted").show();
}); 
});
});
});
```

The problem here is if the user gets more than one friend request then he can only accept the first friend request and the other accept buttons don't work. After refreshing the page only the next accept button works. It takes one refresh of page to accept one friend request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `class` instead of `id`. Because id is unique. So your HTML should be like this

```
<span class="accepted">Accepted</span>
```

instead of

```
<span id="accepted" class="" style="display:none">Accepted</span>
```

and your js code should look like this

```
$(function(){
  $('.accepted').on("click", function(){
     var ths = $(this);
     var I = ths.attr("id");
     var rcv_user = $(ths).siblings("#rcv_user").val();
     var snd_usr = $(ths).siblings("#snd_usr").val();
     var response = $(ths).siblings("#response").val();
     $.post("respond_friend.php", {rcv_user:rcv_user, snd_usr:snd_usr, response:response},
     function(value){
        $('#child').css('background-color', 'white');
        $("#submit").hide();
        $("#ignore").hide();
        $("#or").hide();
        $("#accepted").show();
    });  
  })
})
```

Comment: thanks for you reply! but still the problem is that when a friend request is acepted the value in database gets updated but the accepted succesfully is showing for all friend requests and the background chnages only for the first request, even when i accepts anyothers request